# Can't set Facebook test user work position

Tags: facebook-test-users

Like the title says, I'm having problems with the "Position" field for test users. I've been able to create a work history by creating a organization page, but no matter what i set as "Position" it gets blanked out when I hit save. The problem is, this is the only field we use in our app, and since we haven't been able to add this for a test user, Facebook refuses to approve our app.

To be more specific, this is what the browser sends when I add a position from a test account (snatched from chrome dev tools):

```
position_id:0
position_text:[Whatever text i set as position]
```

I've seen that for my real account, the position_id is set to a number when I choose one of the pre-existing options, but for test users none of these are available. Is it not possible to do this for test users at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a response from a Facebook developer group.

"App Test Users can only interact with objects they created and since they cannot create workplaces you cannot test this with App Test Users."

This is partially correct, you can create an organization page as a test user and set that as your workplace. However you can not fill anything in the "Position" (Job title) field. We managed to get around this by setting the field in our own database manually for test users and check that it works for real users.